# Can I pass a pointer to a pointer, allocate memory, then pass it back?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following code. This works for allocating a single array, but what if you needed to allocate a two dimensional array? How would you go about doing this?

```
#include <iostream>

void alloc(int **num)
{
    *num = new int[5];
    *num[0] = 5;
}

int main()
{
    int *num;
    alloc(&num);
    std::cout << num[0] << std::endl;
    delete [] num;
}
```

My goal is to pass `**char` into the function and have it allocated. Is this possible?

Comment: That looks fine.  I also see `void alloc(int *& num)` which you might want to try.

Comment: This is really a C problem. In C++ you would just use an `std::vector<int>`, or a dedicated type to represent whatever a 2D array means to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know the following code works, but how would I convert this to be 2 dimensional? That is my question, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Is using a vector<> the only way to do it?

Comment: @AxiosAmneisa vector is not the *only* way, but it is the simplest way, and most *difficult to get wrong*. Compared to manual memory management, which is very easy to get wrong, vector is very much preferable.

Comment: @AxiosAmneisa: There's also `list<>` and `deque<>`, but those are for specialized cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what if you needed to allocate a two dimensional array?
>
> My goal is to pass **char into function and have it allocated.

So, what you want is a pointer to an array of pointers (each to an array)? That is different from an 2D array, although often treated as such for simplicity.

Just like you added an additional layer of indirection when you allocated that single array, you can add a layer of indirection to allocate an array of pointers, and the pointed to arrays of integers.

So, you could write a function like `void alloc(int ***num)`. Yes, this is possible, but not very good design.

But using a pointer for the indirection makes the syntax more complex, and has the risk of a user passing a null pointer to the function. Instead, a better alternative would be to use a reference: `void alloc(int **&num)`.

Since the function allocates something and "returns a pointer", it would make more sense to actually `return` the pointer: `int** alloc()`. Much prettier, isn't it? Less indirection is better.

Finally, there is the problem that a user of the function has to know how to delete the allocated memory. Was it allocated with `new` or `new[]`? Maybe even `malloc`? Or does the function perhaps return a pointer to a static object, that must not be deleted? The caller of the function cannot know that unless it is documented separately.

Also, what if one of the allocation fails? There will be an exception, and the earlier allocations will leak.

The C++ way to solve the above 2 problems is to use a RAII container to manage the memory. Since you apparently want to have an array with pointers to arrays, there is a ready made solution in the standard library for you: return a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. If you instead want a proper non-jagged 2D array i.e. a matrix, then you may want to write a custom RAII container for that, possibly using a flat `std::vector<int>` for the implementation. Note that a third party may already have implemented such container.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth view of multiple ways to solve my problem. I Wasn't aware the you could have vectors of vectors. I should be able to solve my problem with what you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like C to me. In C++ I would (maybe) use custom types and not do any manual dynamic allocation. For example

```
typedef std::vector<int> Row;
typedef std::vector<Row> Matrix;

Matrix initMatrix(int nRows,int nCols) {
    return Matrix(nRows,Row(nCols));
}
```

well in that case you dont even need a function but you can just call the constructor (and let `array` allocate the memory for you).

Comment: `std::array` must have the size specified in the template parameters at compile time. `std::vector` is the one that can be sized at runtime :-)